# Trigger event on double click on a word, javascript React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in Reactjs. This has a **p** tag. Inside that there is text.

I want that when ever user double click on any word, it should trigger a function, in which I get the selected text, so that I can save that word in an array.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to implement it?

Comment: try wrapping each work in a tag and listen for double click on that tag. span might be the best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

This should work for all browsers. Attach it to mouseup of your p tag.